# Rails 5: Printing stopped using CSS rules after switching to use CDN to load libraries

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, printing, cdn

In a Rails 5.1 project I recently switched to load all CSS and JS from a CDN like cdnjs. Now everything is included in the `application.html.erb` instead of `application.js` and `application.scss`

Everything has been working fine except I just noticed that when I print a page, it has no CSS styles. Before, this was working fine.

Now when clicking Print and previewing the page, there are no styles applied to the page.
How can I debug this?

Example part of `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

**SOLUTION**:

The solution was to add `, media: "all"` to the `stylesheet_link_tag`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css", media: "all" %>
```

Comment: Check that all CSS link tags have the attribute "media" with value "all" (or at least `screen and print`) https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_media.asp

Comment: That solved it @arieljuod! Adding `,media: "all"` at the end of the `stylesheet_link_tag`